# Comparing 2 columns in a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare if a row in my dataframe as a certain value.

So for example:
`if word = 'bleu' and ink = 'blue'`, I want a new column in my dataframe `'congruent' = 1` and `if not = 0`.

I wrote this code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

word = ['bleu', 'rouge', 'vert', 'jaune']

ink = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow']

my_list_word = [random.choice(word) for _ in range(60)]

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list_word, columns=["word"])

my_list_ink = [random.choice(ink) for _ in range(60)]

df['ink'] = my_list_ink

df['congruent'] = 0

print(df)
```

I tried to do a loop but it didn't work, my congruent column kept all 0.

Someone knows how to do this ?

Thanks!

Comment: What is congruent here ?

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. You should create some form of translation map and draw random values from there. Can you try to tell us the purpose?

Comment: if the word in french is the same than the ink in english.. vert = green, ... In this case, it would be idex 5 bleu = blue

Comment: @vmp and what about Jaune - Yellow?

Comment: It's the stroop test, I need a color word and this word need to be in some color. If the color of the word is the same than the word then it's easy for the participant to say the color of the ink. But if it's wrote blue(bleu) but the ink is green it harder for the participants

Comment: yes in the complete code, i will check for all the possible combinaisons.

Comment: @vmp Perfect, now you asked the right question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for mapping and matching i.e

```
di = dict(zip(word,ink))
df['new'] = (df['word'].map(di) == df['ink']).astype(int)

    word     ink  new
0   bleu     red    0
1  jaune  yellow    1
2  jaune    blue    0
3  jaune  yellow    1
4   vert    blue    0
```

Comment: I'd like to think this answer was inspired by mine somewhat,... you got my vote.

Comment: Somewhat yeah, was in a hurry to post the asnwer. A hint from Anton helped. Not sure if this is exactly what OP is after

Comment: thanks both of you :) I'm not sure how to create the di ?

Comment: Thats the first line of code, pass the two lists to zip, then convert it to dictionary, I hope both of them are sorted in exact way

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is this a merge hah :-)

Comment: @Dark Do you think it's possible to make the congruent happen 50% of the time ? I guess I have to create my congruent condition before my random list..

Comment: I dont think there is a easy answer that, Im not near my machine. Will try once I get back

Answer (score 1):

By using `merge`

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'word':word,'ink':ink})
df.merge(df1.assign(congruent=1),on=['word','ink'],how='left').fillna(0)
```